# SAS ExportPackage command exceeds 8191 characters

Tags: batch-file, sas

We have an automated process for exporting metadata items for promotion, using the ExportPackage commandline utility (documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisag/64088/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003261084.htm)).

The command is written to a .bat file, and then executed (in SAS) via a filename pipe.

We recently observed a strange behaviour when exporting multiple objects (around 60), that we believe is due to the [windows line length limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473) for batch commands.

Basically, one character would be removed (meaning that particular object would not be found), but the rest of the line (after 8191 chars) executes successfully.

Am interested to know:

- Can the ExportPackage command be executed in a way that does not hit the 8191 limitation?
- Alternatively, can the ExportPackage command be split over multiple lines somehow?
- Or is there some way to pass a file to the `-objects` parameter, rather than space separated values?
- Or is it possible to append to (rather than replace) an .spk file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's any answer to this that you're going to like. The documentation you linked states that existing package files with the same names are overwritten and does not mention any way of appending to one.

You can split the command over multiple lines within the batch file using `^` characters, but this still doesn't get around the overall 8191 character limit after recombining the pieces.

Therefore, you will need to do one or more of the following:

- Export your items to separate packages with different filenames or in different folders, e.g. 20 at a time
- Move your objects into a limited set of folders and subfolders before exporting, and export only the top level folders rather than the individual objects. It looks as though you can still use the other command line options to limit which objects are exported.
- Silly option: create a dummy object with dependencies on all of the objects you want to export, mention only that one explicitly in the objects list, and use the `-includeDep` parameter to force the export utility to export all its dependencies.

Disclaimer: I have never actually used the export utility in question.

Comment: thanks..  You're right, it isn't the answer I want, but top marks for the silly option!  I've raised a track with SAS Support, will update if anything comes back else mark this one as correct.

Comment: I got a response - "Unfortunately this is a known issue and there is a defect open for the problem".  The tracking number is 7611510233.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by inserting a dummy character at the 8191 point.  Note that this 8191 length limit is everything in the command AFTER "ExportPackage".

One solution is therefore as follows:

```
  /* If the ExportPackage command line is more than 8191 characters, it will 
     fail due to a windows line length limitation. To avoid this, add a
     hash character at the 8191 point.
  */   
  %let log= \path\to\my.log;
  %let profile= -profile "\path\to\my\dummy\profile.swa";
  %let package= -package "\path\to\my\desired.spk";

  %let str=&my_list_of_objects; /* previously defined */
  %let breakpoint=%eval(
              8191 - %length(%str(&profile &package -objects))-1);
  %if %length(&str)>=&breakpoint %then %let objects=%substr(
    &str,1,&breakpoint-1)#%substr(&str,&breakpoint,%length(&str)-&breakpoint+1);
  %else %let objects=&str;
```

The command could then executed along the lines of:

```
ExportPackage &profile &package &objects -subprop -includeEmptyFolders -log &log
```

**What DIDN'T work:**

*Inserting spaces between quotes at the 8191 point, eg:*

```
"object1"                                 "object2"
```

The extra spaces were ignored and a character was still removed from the second object.

*Inserting spaces within the literal, eg:*

```
"object1                                   "  "object2"
```

Object 1 was not found, presumably due to the trailing spaces.